# Create an r data.table with a date formatted column

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to create a data.table with a date/time formatted column to be populated in the next steps. I've tried a bunch of different functions but I just can't find the one the package wants.

See column3 in the below examples:

```
require(data.table)
num_rows <- 5
dt <- data.table(column1 = character(num_rows),
                 column2 = integer(num_rows),
                 column3 = date(num_rows)
                 )

dt <- data.table(column1 = character(num_rows),
                 column2 = integer(num_rows),
                 column3 = POSIXct(num_rows)
                 )

dt <- data.table(column1 = character(num_rows),
                 column2 = integer(num_rows),
                 column3 = IDateTime(num_rows)
                 )
```

What is the function that creates a date or time column in data.table? I can't find it anywhere.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `integer(num_rows)` makes a vector of 0s, `character(num_rows)` makes a vector of `""`s etc.

So you just initialise your dates to some value, e.g.

```
column3=rep(Sys.time(), num_rows) # POSIXct
```

or

```
column3=rep(Sys.Date(), 3) # Date
```

I'd recommend initialising it to some default date/datetime that makes sense for your application (e.g. your `column2` is initialised to 0 and your `column1` is initialised to `""`). Maybe some default `origin` value e.g. 1970-01-01 00:00 (`column3=rep(as.POSIXct('1970-01-01 00:00'), num_rows)`)